# Form doesn't get submitted when there's click event on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have form where's a click event listener on the submit button. When the submit button is clicked the event click event listener on the button gets fired, but the form doesn't get submitted.

Here's my code:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form action="/customer/create" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <button type="submit" class="has-button-spinner">Create Customer</button>
</form>

<!-- JS -->
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.has-button-spinner');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const target = e.currentTarget;

    target.classList.add('is-loading');
    target.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you disable your `<button>`, you prevent its action *(submitting the form)* from taking place.

Instead of listening to the `click` event of your button, listen to the `submit` event of your form :

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

forms.forEach((form) => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    const target = form.querySelector('button.has-button-spinner');

    target.classList.add('is-loading');
    target.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="/customer/create" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <button type="submit" class="has-button-spinner">Create Customer</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the better solution, but you should include *why* it doesn't work for a `click` event

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I added a short explanation.

Comment: Darn you answered while I typed mine :( Good Answer though!

Answer (score 1):

As @Zenoo said, listening to the `onClick`-event prevents the actual button action (`submit`) from being executed, so you could either:

#### Submit the form in the handler:

HTML:

```
<!-- add id to form -->
<form id="form_create_customer" action="/customer/create" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <button type="submit" class="has-button-spinner">Create Customer</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.has-button-spinner');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const target = e.currentTarget;

        target.classList.add('is-loading');
        target.setAttribute('disabled', true);

        document.getElementById("form_create_customer").submit();
    });
});
```

#### Change the handler to listen to `onSubmit` instead of `onClick`:

HTML:

```
<!-- add id to form -->
<form id="form_create_customer" action="/customer/create" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <button type="submit" class="has-button-spinner">Create Customer</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.has-button-spinner');

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.parentNode.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        // we're not using the event data to avoid
        // having to find the button from the form
        // on each submit event
        button.classList.add('is-loading');
        button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Zenoo What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Zenoo you mean `button.parentNode.addEventListener`? Did you by any chance overlook the `.parentNode`?

Comment: It appears I did, sorry for that ^^